# App crashes onItemClick

Tags: java, android, onitemclicklistener

My App crashes when I click on an item. My code has no errors in eclipse but when I click on one of the items it say (Unfortunately the App has stopped working) and the LogCat spits out a bunch of errors one of them is: 02-14 04:33:20.010: E/MessageQueue-JNI(774): java.lang.NullPointerException. Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

```
package com.carouseldemo.main;

import com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel;

import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter; 
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemClickListener;
/**import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemSelectedListener;*/
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselItem;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.testmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Carousel carousel = (Carousel)findViewById(R.id.carousel);

        carousel.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            public void onItemClick(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {    
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
                                               (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

                TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.selected_item);
                text.setText("This is a custom toast");

                Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setView(layout);
                toast.show();


                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                        String.format("%s has been clicked", 
                        ((CarouselItem)parent.getChildAt(position)).getName()), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();z
    }



        });


       /** carousel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

            public void onItemSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                final TextView txt = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.selected_item));

                switch(position){
                case 0:
                    txt.setText("The cat (Felis catus), also known as the domestic cat or housecat to distinguish it from other felids and felines, is a small, usually furry, domesticated, carnivorous mammal that is valued by humans for its companionship and for its ability to hunt vermin and household pests. Cats have been associated with humans for at least 9,500 years, and are currently the most popular pet in the world. Owing to their close association with humans, cats are now found almost everywhere in the world.");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    txt.setText("The hippopotamus (Hippopotamus amphibius), or hippo, from the ancient Greek for \"river horse\" (á¼±Ï€Ï€Î¿Ï€ÏŒÏ„Î±Î¼Î¿Ï‚), is a large, mostly herbivorous mammal in sub-Saharan Africa, and one of only two extant species in the family Hippopotamidae (the other is the Pygmy Hippopotamus.) After the elephant, the hippopotamus is the third largest land mammal and the heaviest extant artiodactyl.");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    txt.setText("A monkey is a primate, either an Old World monkey or a New World monkey. There are about 260 known living species of monkey. Many are arboreal, although there are species that live primarily on the ground, such as baboons. Monkeys are generally considered to be intelligent. Unlike apes, monkeys usually have tails. Tailless monkeys may be called \"apes\", incorrectly according to modern usage; thus the tailless Barbary macaque is called the \"Barbary ape\".");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    txt.setText("A mouse (plural: mice) is a small mammal belonging to the order of rodents. The best known mouse species is the common house mouse (Mus musculus). It is also a popular pet. In some places, certain kinds of field mice are also common. This rodent is eaten by large birds such as hawks and eagles. They are known to invade homes for food and occasionally shelter.");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    txt.setText("The giant panda, or panda (Ailuropoda melanoleuca, literally meaning \"black and white cat-foot\") is a bear native to central-western and south western China.[4] It is easily recognized by its large, distinctive black patches around the eyes, over the ears, and across its round body. Though it belongs to the order Carnivora, the panda's diet is 99% bamboo.");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    txt.setText("Rabbits (or, colloquially, bunnies) are small mammals in the family Leporidae of the order Lagomorpha, found in several parts of the world. There are eight different genera in the family classified as rabbits, including the European rabbit (Oryctolagus cuniculus), cottontail rabbits (genus Sylvilagus; 13 species), and the Amami rabbit (Pentalagus furnessi, an endangered species on Amami ÅŒshima, Japan)");
                    break;
                }
                            }

            public void onNothingSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent) {          } 


        }
        );*/

    }
     }
```

LogCat error log:

```
02-14 14:38:09.137: E/InputEventReceiver(996): Exception dispatching input event.
02-14 14:38:09.148: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at com.carouseldemo.main.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:50)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.performItemClick(CarouselAdapter.java:261)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel.onSingleTapUp(Carousel.java:967)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:588)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel.onTouchEvent(Carousel.java:311)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7239)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7419)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-14 14:38:09.207: E/MessageQueue-JNI(996):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-14 14:38:09.247: D/AndroidRuntime(996): Shutting down VM
02-14 14:38:09.247: W/dalvikvm(996): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.carouseldemo.main.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:50)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.performItemClick(CarouselAdapter.java:261)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel.onSingleTapUp(Carousel.java:967)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:588)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel.onTouchEvent(Carousel.java:311)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7239)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7419)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-14 14:38:09.327: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you point out which line is line 50

Comment: please check if ((CarouselItem)parent.getChildAt(position)).getName() leeds to the NPE.

Comment: Hi Stefan, it does, so how do i fix it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parent.getChildAt(i) will give the i-th VISIBLE child view of the parent, NOT the child view representing the i-th item.

Let me explain in another way. Assume that your AdapterView has 100 items. You may expect parent.getChildAt(99) will give the view representing the last item: This is wrong. For performance issue, AdapterView creates child views for the items that need to be shown currently. For example, if you are scrolled at the top of the list, and you have 5 items shown, the AdapterView probably have 5 or 6 child views. In this case, parent.getChildAt(99) will give null reference.

Actaully, the child view that is clicked is already given via the onItemClicked method: the second'view' argument. You may modify your code as follows.

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
    String.format("%s has been clicked",    
    ((CarouselItem)view).getName()), 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Edit:

Furthermore, following code fragment is also suspicious.

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
                                       (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));


        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.selected_item);
        text.setText("This is a custom toast");
```

Here, you are inflating toast_layout.xml into a view and add it to another view (R.id.toast_layout_root) which is already attached to the application window. This will cause the view inflated from toast_layout.xml be shown in the main application window.

However, you use the inflated view as the layout of the toast which is rendered as a separate window.

Comment: Hi Jiyong, i tried using your code but it does the same thing. My app crashes? Could you please give more suggestions please. Thank you

Comment: Does using this code give you the same error message as before, or a new one?

Comment: text.setText("This is a custom toast");  is the line 50 of my code.

Comment: So Jiyong what do u think i should do?

Comment: Well, it seems that R.id.selected_item does not exist in your toast_layout.xml.

Comment: Thanks jiyong . Got it. I deleted the LayoutInflator segment since i dont need it anymore in my code and now the app does not crash onItemClick.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like line 50 in your logcat is referring to this line:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
    String.format("%s has been clicked",    
    ((CarouselItem)parent.getChildAt(position)).getName()), 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I'm guessing it's getting a NullPointerException from this part:

```
((CarouselItem)parent.getChildAt(position)).getName())
```

I would recommend running it with the debugger, add a breakpoint at this line, and take a look at everything to see what's failing. Maybe even capture the CarouselItem in a variable in the line above to make it easier to analyze:

```
CarouselItem item = (CarouselItem) parent.getChildAt(position);
```

Comment: Thank You Ben, i tried it could not find anything though. I will keep looking in the mean time more suggestions are more than welcome please. Thank you.